# Requested module experienced an error while loading - Server - Data:11

Tags: module, lua, roblox

Yeah So, I'm coding a Roblox game and this script gets an error every time, I even restarted roblox studio to try fixing it but it didn't work and I tried messing around with the code but I couldn't figure it out, can someone please help?

Script:

```
local PetModule = require(ServerModules.PetModule)
```

Module Code:

```
local module = {}

local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage") 

local Pet = ReplicatedStorage.Pet

function module.EquipPet(Player, PetName)
    local PetModel = Pet:FindFirstChild(PetName)
    if PetModel then
        PetModel = PetModel:Clone()
        PetModel.Parent = workspace.Pet:FindFirstChild((Player.Name))
        if Player then
            local Character = Player.Character
            if Character then
                if not Character.HumanoidRootPart:FindFirstChild("PetAttachments") then
                    local PetAttachments = Instance.new("Folder")
                    PetAttachments.Name = "PetAttachments"
                    PetAttachments.Parent = Character.HumanoidRootPart


                    local PetAttachments = Character.HumanoidRootPart:FindFirstChild("PetAttachments")
                    if PetAttachments then
                        local att0 = Instance.new("Attachment")
                        att0.Name = "Attachment1"
                        att0.Position = PetModel:FindFirstChild("AttachmentPosition").Value
                        att0.Parent =Character.HumanoidRootPart

                        local att1 = Instance.New("Attachment")
                        att1.Name = "Attachment2"
                        att1.Parent = PetModel.PrimaryPart

                        local AlignPosition = Instance.new("AlignPosition")
                        AlignPosition.Attachment0 = att0
                        AlignPosition.Attachment1 = att1
                        AlignPosition.RigidityEnabled = false
                        AlignPosition.MaxForce = PetModel.MaxForce.Value
                        AlignPosition.Responsiveness = PetModel.Responsiveness.Value
                        AlignPosition.Parent = PetModel.PrimaryPart

                        local AlignOrientation = Instance.new("AlignOrientation")
                        AlignOrientation.Attachment0 = att0
                        AlignOrientation.Attachment1 = att1
                        AlignOrientation.RigidityEnabled = false
                        AlignOrientation.MaxTorque = PetModel.MaxForce.Value
                        AlignOrientation.Responsiveness = PetModel.Responsiveness.Value
                        AlignOrientation.Parent = PetModel.PrimaryPart
                        
                        game:GetService("RunService").Heartbeat:Connect(function()
                            att0.Position = PetModel.AttachmentPosition.Value
                            AlignPosition.MaxForce = PetModel.MaxForce.Value
                            AlignOrientation.MaxTorque = PetModel.MaxForce.Value
                            AlignPosition.Responsiveness = PetModel.Responsiveness
                        end)
                    end
                end
            end
        end 
    end

    function module.UnequipPet(Player)

    end

    function module.UnequipAllPet(Player)

    end

return module

end
```

**If anyone could help me fix this it would be great.**

Answer (score 0):

make sure to put "return module" at the end!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    return module
```

is within the function. Try to put it free at the end of the code and...

I'm not sure, but I think it's because you're creating an event connection within module, I had this problem right now. I just stopped creating events within the Module and the problem stopped.

Try removing this from de Code.

```
game:GetService("RunService").Heartbeat:Connect(function()
     att0.Position = PetModel.AttachmentPosition.Value
     AlignPosition.MaxForce = PetModel.MaxForce.Value
     AlignOrientation.MaxTorque = PetModel.MaxForce.Value
     AlignPosition.Responsiveness = PetModel.Responsiveness
end)
```